# Ошибка звука Питон

Tags: python

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os, sys, webbrowser, pygame
from gtts import gTTS

def talk(words):
    print(words)
    os.system("say" + words)

talk("Hello")
```

итог

```
"sayHello" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Comment: попробуйте так: `os.system("D:/_Qt/Mp3/zvuki_prirody-td.wav")`, указав свой путь к файлу `.wav`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.system` выполняет команду в субшелле.

Проще говоря, вы пытаетесь выполнить команду `sayHello` в командной строке *Windows*, а такой команды попросту не существует.

Если же вы пытаетесь преобразовать текст в речь, то попробуйте использовать библиотеку `pyttsx3`.
Вот, как может выглядеть код:

```
import pyttsx3 

engine = pyttsx3.init()


def speak(input_data):
    engine.say(input_data)
    engine.runAndWait()
    engine.stop()


def text_to_speech():
    text = input('Введите текст: ')
    if text:
        speak(text)


while True:
    text_to_speech()
```